# Next.js Custom Server not working on Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, proxy, next.js

My Next.js App deployed on Firebase. I use custom server(server.ts) to launch App(node src/server.ts). Next code is server.ts and firebaseFunctions.js.
server.ts is working on local so proxy is working.
Why doesn't it work on fierbase? Please tell me the solution.

```
// @ts-ignore
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  console.log("sercer")

  server.use(
    "/api",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "https://tus-schedule-api.herokuapp.com",
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );

  server.get("/super_test", (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send();
  });

  server.all("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

```
const { join } = require("path");
const { https } = require("firebase-functions");
const { default: next } = require("next");

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const nextjsDistDir = join("src", require("./src/next.config.js").distDir);

const nextjsServer = next({
  dev: isDev,
  conf: {
    distDir: nextjsDistDir,
  },
});
const nextjsHandle = nextjsServer.getRequestHandler();

exports.nextjsFunc = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return nextjsServer.prepare().then(() => nextjsHandle(req, res));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and then somehow it started to work after fiddeling arround.
Below is an example of a simplified cloud function that works locally and also deployed to Firebase Cloud Functions.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const app = express();
app.use('/api', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://www.example.org', changeOrigin: true }));
export const expressApi = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I also have a hosting rewrites config as per below

```
  "hosting": 
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "expressApi"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I would suggest you try this example and see if it works for you, try to reduce your problem to the minimum amount of code to identify what is causing the issue.

Also some things you may want to try :

- Make sure you use the latest firebase tools : `npm install -g firebase-tools` (I'm using  8.4.3 right now)
- Try deleting everything in the folder "\functions\node_modules" and then run `npm install`
- Reboot your computer, it may seem stupid but sometimes things are cached and it breaks things.

Good luck.